# How to keep Num Lock on at startup

Tags: windows

How do I change my computer so that the Num Lock is on at startup?
I am using a PC with windows 8.1 
I have read other responses but they do not work for me.

Comment: Have you tried enabling num lock at startup in bios?

Comment: Please edit your post and tell us what you already tried, or risk that we suggest what you already tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
HKCU\Control Panel\Keyboard
```

Change `InitialKeyboardIndicators` to `2`

`2` = Num Lock on, `0` = Num Lock off

[Technet Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978657.aspx)

You might want to create a backup, though...

> **Update**

Also check `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard`

`InitialKeyboardIndicators` should be set to `2147483648`

> **Update**

Just in case it's not clear: Those keys are found in the registry:

Press your [image] + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Return</kbd> "regedit" (without the marks). You will then find a tree like in your windows explorer, wherein you can find above keys. `HKCU` = `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`

Comment: Current User will work after login. I think the user wants to do this before login.

Comment: Then she should check HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard\InitialKeyboardIndicators and set this to "2147483648"